# ASP.NET 5 MVC 6: How to configure startup to send a html file when not on any mvc route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, react-router

I'm building a SPA application using React-Router to handle the front-end routing.

I'm trying to configure the ASP.NET 5 Startup.cs file to use MVC but when a route does not match any of my API routes to send the index.html file so that it will be able to handle react-routers browser history implementation as stated [here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md).

So far i've only been able to get it to send the index.html file when on the default route, i.e. nothing after the localhost:3000.

My Startup Configure method so far. Thank you

```
        app.UseIdentity();
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
        app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions {
            DefaultFileNames = new List<string> { "index.html"}
        });
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc();
```

Comment: Essentially this is handing 404 errors, if a route/page doesn't exist then you want to show something else. Check out this question and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421164/mvc-6-404-not-found

Comment: Thank you, i'll give that a go

Answer (score 6):

Pretty simple, with `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/");`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/");

    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
        );
    });
}
```

This will return the `index.html` page in your `wwwroot`, even if you get a 404. It will however only change the page, but not the URL.

**Alternatively**, you might *not* want to do a page redirect since you are doing a SPA, but if you really need to update the URL you can just do a simple redirect from a controller, like so:

```
public class RedirectController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Redirect(Url.Content("~/"));
    }
}
```

and then in your startup update this:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/redirect");
```

Comment: Very nice!

Note that the order is important (`app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` should be before `app.UseDefaultFiles` from what I have tested).

Also `app.UseMvc()` is enough if you don't have any "view", just index.html for your SPA.

Instead of defining `RedirectController` (if you need a 302 redirection), you can use `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects` (did not test myself). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling

Comment: thanks a lot @Nick De Beer, as your answer highlighted that `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute()` needs to be passed an URL, not a "path to the view"